# Dplyr min and max aggregations extremely slow with na.rm = TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large dataframe which I need to aggregate and get the min and max of a numeric column. This runs reasonably fast, until I introduce NA values and use `na.rm = TRUE`. Then aggregating the first 50000 rows takes about as long as it took to aggregate the full dataframe of 3M rows. Aggregating the full dataframe with NA runs for days. Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

```r
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

n <- 3000000
h <- stri_rand_strings(40000, 15, pattern = "[a-z]")
sp <- stri_rand_strings(10000, 15, pattern = "[a-z]")
y <- round(runif(n, 1800, 2000))
r <- round(runif(n, 1, 100))
df <- data.frame(h = sample(h, n, replace = TRUE), sp = sample(sp, n, replace = TRUE), y, r)

# takes 12 seconds

df %>%
  group_by(h, sp) %>%
  summarize(r = sum(r), min_y = min(y), max_y = max(y))

# introduce NA

df$y[sample(nrow(df), 1500000)] <- NA

# first 50000 rows, takes about as long

df[1:50000,] %>%
  group_by(h, sp) %>%
  summarize(r = sum(r), min_y = min(y, na.rm = TRUE), max_y = max(y, na.rm = TRUE))
```

## Edit

Fixed multiple issues with the reprex.

Comment: Are you open to other packages? You can try `collapse::fmin` and `collapse::fmax`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `summarize(n = sum(r), min_x = min(y), max_x = max(y))`? And I cannot reproduce the timings differences, neither with the code above nor when including `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: With package `data.table` I'm getting less than half a second for the whole df.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Apologies, the example had several issues which are now fixed. For me the issue only occurs with na.rm = TRUE.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use `data.table` for larger stuff.

```
> library(data.table); library(tictoc)
> tic()
> setDT(df)[, .(r=sum(r), min_y=min(y), max_y=max(y)), by=.(h, sp)]
                       h              sp   r min_y max_y
      1: qsldsgxadexvwao jhaynkgbkaorwyr   5  1812  1812
      2: hjlgvsfmdpksxem gacigwhylyuqsva  94  1823  1823
      3: irrmryyeumpqvrq tvbyjddlfhquchv  73  1900  1900
      4: ftweijwfyiarrvb krmhufufdeqtmnw  11  1811  1811
      5: itcelkxagodzkfv hyidznidwanrpih  27  1846  1846
     ---                                                
2988785: zzzafinxysuehaq jlfolyropllkpwj  52  1991  1991
2988786: wfnheuiqjthsveu jcblanyuakutyjd  20  1818  1818
2988787: orxxjlomvogexbl lwpvntwfntqnhbx  50  1943  1943
2988788: pfvavwmlhvwxrdn pvnfhtbsvwphihj  20  1946  1946
2988789: varectekdjpybay gurhxwcbgsexihs 100  1807  1807
> toc()
0.925 sec elapsed
```